# Matlab: why is the input wrong?

Tags: matlab, input

I have an image that named 'binary3.tiff'.

[image: This is my image]

I am asked:
"In the following function (is called func) the images are given as matrices of doubles. In those images 1 represents the object and 0 (black) represents the background."

what should the input be?
I tried:

```
img = imread('binary3.tiff');
img2 = double(img)/255;
newimg = func(img2);
```

but it doesn't work.

please help me.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  Be more specific what you expect to happen and what happens instead

Comment: What are the values of `img`? What are the values of `img2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more details about what `func` does and the nature of the error you're getting, I can't help you much, but you can do this instead:

```
img2 = double(img > 0);
```

to ensure that the values in the input image are binary, and give it another go. Note that instead of `0` you can, of course, put any threshold number below which it is considered "background".

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be due to the fact that imread assumes tiff images use the CMYK color space instead of the RGB color space, thus making `img=imread('image.tiff')` a matrix whose thrid dimension has size 4, instead of 3, due to this, some functions don't work properly on `img`, for instance, `image(img)` will throw an error, this is probably why you interpret the input as being incorrect.

The format of `img=imread('image.tiff')` is uint8, that means every value is an integer between 0 and 255, if you want to conver them to doubles between 0 and 1 it is correct to do `img2=double(img)/255` as dividing a matrix by a scalar is the same as dividing each element by that scalar.

Finally, if you are sure your image is in the RGB color space you can simply discard the 4th color layer of the matrix by doing `img=imread('image.tif')` and then `img=img(:,:,1:3)` if you do this, AND the image is indeed in RGB, commands such as `image(img)` will work fine.